# Sench Touch Setup in windows Pc for developing mobile applications

Tags: windows, tomcat, sencha-touch

How to setup sencha touch in a windows pc without using Sencha cmd. I am using only Apache Tomcat for running my application.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need Eclipse(of any version. i prefer kepler). You dont need to install Sencha CMD just you download the [Sencha Touch library](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/) and use inside the application. For better coding use Spkjet editor or VJET editor.

You can run your application as webapp inside apache tomcat.